# I want to cut off my hand, or Throw compilation error if class from a specific namespace is used in Silverlight :)

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

For example, i want to restrict myself from using System.Threading namespace in my project. I want an exception (compilation exception) to be throwed if I use any class from System.Threading namespace.

**Is there a way to do this in Silverlight?**

---

If there is no way to do this, then i will be forsed to use [alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31671/alex)
advice :)

Comment: *Max Signed Byte Hours* has a good guide to doing that.

Comment: could you plz give me a direct link? if it's not so hard for you :)

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/127_Hours) :P

Comment: What you are describing is an extremely unconventional solution to a problem (that's why it's hard to implement). Can you tell us what problem you are solving with this mechanism so you can leverage our problem-solving abilities to the fullest?

Comment: well i just want to give a task to other developer, and i want to restrict him from using some namespaces and classes.. becose i want my Silverlight code be portable from Silverlight 4 to Silverlight 2... (plz do not propose me to write application in Silverlight 2, it's not a solution in my situation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a custom [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) rule to enforce this.

Comment: could you write a simple example (for System.Threading namespace)?

Comment: Read this http://scottwhite.blogspot.com/2008/11/creating-custom-stylecop-rules-in-c.html.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like `System.Threading` is implemented in `mscorlib.dll`, no.

Actually I can think of something that one might try (using a tool to modify the IL in `mscorlib` and have every constructor in `System.Threading` throw `NotSupportedException`, then reference the modified `mscorlib` instead of the original) but I don't know if it's possible and I wouldn't be caught dead doing it. So let's forget about that and move on.